# Short-hand to add many key/value pairs to an existing JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

If I have an existing POJO and want to add some key/value pairs to it, I normally do it like so:

```
var existingObject = {
    firstValue: 'hello'
};

/* some time later... */

existingObject.secondValue = 'world';
existingObject.thirdValue = 'new value';
existingObject.fourthValue = 'another value';
existingObject.fifthValue = 'another value';
existingObject.sixthValue = 'another value';
existingObject.seventhValue = 'another value';
existingObject.eighthValue = 'another value';
existingObject.adInfinitum = 'again and again...';
```

But I wonder if there is a more efficient way than this longhanded approach? Note however, that I am looking for alternatives to creating a temp object and calling `extend`.

Also, simply storing the object in a smaller variable (like `var a = existingObject;` and using `a.newValue = 'something'`)  isn't a solution I am looking for.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please elaborate. Where do the values come from? Which part could be made DRYer?

Comment: I'm assuming you can't simply add them all at instantiation like you did firstValue?  You're specifically talking about adding additional values after instantiation?

Comment: How about you use an array: `existingObject.values = ["hello", "world", "new value", "another value", "again and again..."]` and so on.

Comment: Yeah, this lacks so much detail..

Comment: The long-hand approach *is* "efficient", if not a bit tedious - but a proper IDE/editor should sort all that out.

Comment: Given your restrictions, no, there is not.

Comment: @kman: Yes, you are correct that the values will be added after some time (like AJAX, etc).

Comment: @Matt Ball: I'm asking about the repetition of typing the `existingObject` variable, and whether there is a way to reduce the tedious-ness of doing so.

Comment: Autocomplete, multiple-cursor typing or simple copy-paste.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the new ES6 method `Object.assign`, much of the repeated boilerplate can be eliminated. Example:

```
var existingObject = {
    firstValue: 'hello'
};

/* some time later... */

Object.assign(existingObject, {
  secondValue: 'world',
  thirdValue: 'new value',
  fourthValue: 'another value',
  fifthValue: 'another value',
  sixthValue: 'another value',
  seventhValue: 'another value',
  eighthValue: 'another value',
  adInfinitum: 'again and again...'
});
// existingObject now has all these properties
```

This will do it without using other temporary variables or calling some external `extend` method.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.

Alternatively, the best I can suggest, is a function that takes variable arguments, alternating between keys and values. Just make it a bare function, optionally taking an existing object to extend.